# Difference between catch(exception &e) and "catch(...)?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I'm seeing tutorials on C++ exception handling, and the instructor is showing this example:

```
catch (exception & e)
{
}
```

But I remember a much older syntax:

```
catch (...)
{
}
```

What's the difference, or which one should I be using?

Thank you.

Comment: You can throw anything, not only things inherited from `std::exception`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I know we can throw a specific out of range exception or divide by zero exception. But I'm more of a C# guy, so the syntax looks a bit foreign to me... Do the two examples I posted in the original questions serve the same purpose?

Comment: @Stout The first one catches only exceptions of types that derive from `std::exception`. But you can throw any objects of arbitrary types as exceptions in C++. The `...` version catches *any* exception. See linked duplicate.

Comment: Got it. That was helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: `catch(...)` isn't "much older syntax". It means something different, as other comments have pointed out.